# Configuring UI access via HTTP NIFI

Tags: http, configuration, apache-nifi

I am looking to configure NIFI UI access via HTTP. I've set the values necessary (Or so I thought) in `nifi.properties`.

properties set:

`nifi.web.http.host=192.168.1.99`
`nifi.web.http.port=8080`

I know NIFI does allow for both HTTP and HTTPS to be used simultaneously so I removed the below default values and left them unset:

`nifi.web.https.host=`
`nifi.web.https.port=`

Once I saved this file, I restarted the service `systemctl restart nifi.service` to see if it would read the new config file. I ran `netstat -plnt` to see if the port was open to no avail.

Comment: there might be some security related properties.  set them to false as well.

Comment: Thank you, I opted to just keep it https for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the HTTP values? If not, you're not providing a port for NiFi to listen to.

Comment: I did and I it didn't work.  Because this was a time critical project I kept with https.

Comment: Ok. If you need HTTP, note that starting with version 1.14.0 made NiFi start with TLS enabled by default.